# SQL scalar function returns unexpected result

Tags: sql, function, scalar

I can't figure out why these 2 things return different results.

This SQL returns the letter P:

```
SELECT PROVIDERS.PROVIDERNBR, CONTRACTS.PROVIDERPARSTATUS
FROM
   dwpresentation_prod.dbo.PROVIDERS
   INNER JOIN dwpresentation_prod.dbo.CONTRACTS
      ON PROVIDERS.PROVIDERNBR = CONTRACTS.PROVIDERNBR
WHERE
   PROVIDERS.PROVIDERNBR = 'P18292'
   AND CONTRACTS.TERMDATE = 0;
```

But this returns a zero length string:

```
SELECT dbo.PENDS_BAA_ParProvider('P18292');
```

Here is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar)
RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @result varchar (15);
   SET @result = IsNull((
      SELECT
         CASE 
         WHEN PROVIDERPARSTATUS IS NULL THEN ''
         WHEN PROVIDERPARSTATUS = 'P' THEN 'P'
         ELSE '' END
      FROM
         dwpresentation_prod.dbo.Providers PROVIDERS
         INNER JOIN dwPresentation_Prod.dbo.Contracts CONTRACTS
            ON PROVIDERS.ProviderNbr = CONTRACTS.ProviderNbr
      WHERE
         PROVIDERS.ProviderNbr = @ProviderNumber
         AND CONTRACTS.TermDate = 0
   ), '');

   RETURN @result;
END;
```

Without soliloquies on why am I using a function rather than an SQL statement (the answer has mostly to do with experimentation and learning), I'm wondering WHY the function produces a zero length string.

**EDIT**
My current function now looks like this, but STILL returns a ZLS, as opposed to P:

Current function - STILL returns ZLS

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar)

RETURNS varchar(15)
AS BEGIN

Declare @result varchar (15)

set @result=isnull((SELECT
                CASE 
                    WHEN PROVIDERPARSTATUS Is Null THEN ''
                    WHEN PROVIDERPARSTATUS='P' THEN 'P'
                ELSE '' END

```
            FROM dwpresentation_prod.dbo.Providers PROVIDERS
                INNER JOIN dwPresentation_Prod.dbo.Contracts CONTRACTS
            ON PROVIDERS.ProviderNbr = CONTRACTS.ProviderNbr

            WHERE (PROVIDERS.ProviderNbr=@ProviderNumber AND CONTRACTS.TermDate=0)),'')
```

Return @result
END
GO

Comment: I don't think the top query returns P.  I think it returns 6.

Comment: The answer has to be that the `PROVIDERPARSTATUS` is not equal to `P` for `ProviderNbr = 'P18292'`. What if it's equal to another character that only *looks* like a P?

Comment: @DanBracuk He means the second column of the first SQL statement, not the result of the `Len`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the function definition.  This:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar)
```

is equivalent to:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar(1))
```

In SQL Server, *always* include a length with character types:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar(255))
```

Comment: Thank you - I was starting to "sniff" in that direction, and that's why I started testing Lengths of things (sorry - it was a typo to leave the Len() in there when I posted the question though).  But now I have edited it to return varchar(15), but it STILL doesn't return P.

Comment: My current function is this, but it still returns a zero length string:

Comment: Gordon:  OK, I changed the first line to be:
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PENDS_BAA_ParProvider](@ProviderNumber varchar(15))
and you are right, now I get 'P' back.  But I"m more confused now, and have a couple questions:
1) Why isn't it the RETURN line that 'matters' in that regard?
2) Why would it have mattered in this particular case, since P is only one character anyway?
..And thank you

Comment: @Isaac . . . The issue is passing in one character rather than a string.  You think you are passing in `'P18292'`, but it is getting converted to `'P'` and hence doesn't match the conditions you have in the function.

Comment: Feeling a bit silly, but I understand now. I was focusing on the return but you were referring to the passed parameter. Thank you Gordon!  I'm new to T-SQL, and trying to hit the learning curve on a tight timeline.  Thanks for being patient.